Can I load config files for my project (tsconfig, eslintrc, prettierrc, etc.) from an npm package?
I use the same config files and utility functions across all my projects. I'm working on a shared library that I will host on npm (on an internal server).
If I add config files to this shared library, can I somehow implement these config files in new projects?
In other words, I would like to download and implement config files from a shared library, hosted on npm, in the simplest way possible.
new-project/
  src/
  test/
  package.json <= download shared library package
  ...
    <other config files are provided by shared library somehow>
  ...      


https://github.com/tsconfig/bases, https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/shareable-configs, ...
